# onKeyPress method on TextInput for Android

Tags: android, react-native, textinput, onkeypress

I've been trying to catch the keyboard's events within a `TextInput` in `react-native`.

By reading the component's doc (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html) I noticed the `onKeyPress` function which fits perfectly what I need. But it is labelled as `ios` only. I haven't found anything about an `android` workaround except this issue (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1882) which has been inactive for a couple months now ...

What I'd need to do is calling a specific method when `Backspace` is pressed and it looks like it can only be done for `ios` for now ...

Do you guys know any workaround for this ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6):

`onKeyPress` is now supported on Android.

From version `v0.55.2` ([commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/c9ff0bc212b680232f7379fba7b9332927075c3c))

Note hat the hardware keyboard inputs are not supported on Android, only the soft keyboard inputs.

Meaning, if you test this on an Android emulator and you type on your computer keyboard, those inputs are not be handled.
So, go ahead and press the soft keyboard on the emulator with the mouse.

Comment: Thanks for this info ! Great answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I've come across this problem, too. I can tell you, what I did. It's not elegant, but it will do the job, until it's implemented for Android too.

In Android you can [handle key events](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html) in Activity. Also, you can [send events to JavaScript](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#sending-events-to-javascript). That's everything you need.

In js file (e.g. componentDidMount) add listener.

```
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('onKeyPressed', yourFunction)
```

In your MainActivity add something like this.

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   WritableMap params;
   // params.put something
   // filter only Backspace events if you wish etc.
   reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                           .emit("onKeyPressed", params);
}
```

It will be send every time a key was pressed. Don't forget to remove listener (e.g. componentDidUnmount or whenever you don't need it anymore). Also, if you have multiple `TextInput`, keep track of what is focused, so you don't mix it up.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you obtain the reactContext?

Comment: within activity `getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext()`

Comment: This only works for hardware keyboard events. It does not fire for me when the backspace key is pressed on an on-screen keyboard.

Comment: @Martin your line with code contains unreadable symbols, please fix it
```<code>getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentRea&zwnj;&#8203;ctContext()</code>```

Comment: It doesn't fire for backspace in simulator, but works fine on real device (just tested). And this package implements this method btw https://github.com/kevinejohn/react-native-keyevent

Answer (score 1):

You can use [onChangeText](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onchangetext) of TextInput and inside the function supplied to onChangeText, you can check if the last entered text has One character less than the earlier text in the TextInput. If it has, then it means user pressed backspace and you can trigger/call your specific method.

```
 class SearchScreenBase extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { lastText: '',
    };
    // Bind callback methods to make `this` the correct context.
    this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);
   }
   _onChange(newText) {
      var oldText = this.state.lastText;
      if(newText.length === (oldText.length-1)){
         //INSERT TRIGGER FUNCTION HERE
      }
      this.setState({
               lastText: newText
      });
   }
   render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        onChangeText = {this._onChange}
        editable = {true}
        maxLength = {40}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

It worked for me pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your MainActivity.java

```
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
```

...

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext().getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit("onKeyPressed", keyCode);
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Now this will return the keyCode corresponding to the button pressed

Add this to your component to listen to the emitted keyCode, for e.g. I am adding the listener in componentWillMount

```
componentWillMount = () => {
    this.keyPressedListener = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('onKeyPressed', yourFunction);
}
```

Handle yourFunction according to your requirements and don't forget to remove the listener afterward.